# Are wet wipes subject to the TSA's 3-1-1 Liquids Rule?

Tags: air-travel, usa, tsa

If I want to bring a packet of wet wipes with me on a plane, do I need to put them into the one-quart ziploc bag with all my other 3 ounce liquid containers?  The [TSA 3-1-1 Liquids Rule page](http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/3-1-1-liquids-rule) doesn't mention wet wipes.

Comment: @pnuts Well you could say that wet wipes contain a liquid.

Comment: @pacoverflow your body contains liquids..

Comment: There was a comedian who foresaw that with the liquid rules becoming tighter and tighter passengers will soon be asked to go to the bathroom before security screening.

Comment: @JoErNanO If that happened, I will pee in the clear bad, I will make sure it is 100ml.

Comment: I don't think their x-ray can tell such things contain liquid in the first place.  I used to travel with ampoules of liquid medicine, after a couple of times where I didn't get them told I realized they didn't see them--and I quit telling them.  I was never questioned about it despite sometimes carrying a total of about a quart of liquid.

Comment: Pro Tip: If you use your alcohol-based wet wipe to wipe down / sanitize your tray and handrests, do not for the love of FAA look at the used wet wipe before disposing of it. You'll never be able to sit in a plane seat again.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The other answers are correct, but they rely on the assumption that wet wipes are not liquid, gel, aerosol, cream, or paste, without any evidence that the TSA would accept that.  As you correctly pointed out in a comment, wet wipes contain liquid.

How can we check whether the liquid contained in wet wipes causes them to fall under the 3-1-1 rule?  Try the Prohibited Items page of the TSA web site:

http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/prohibited-items

Here, there is a box with the text "When I Fly, Can I Bring My...?"  If you type "wet wipes" into the box, and click the "Go" button, you will get a pop-up window informing you that

> You may transport this item in carry-on baggage or in checked baggage.
>   For items you wish to carry-on, you should check with the airline to
>   ensure that the item will fit in the overhead bin or underneath the
>   seat of the airplane.

Comment: Fantastic answer.  I typed "toothpaste" into the search box and it mentioned the 3-1-1 rule.  So this is proof that wet wipes are not subject to the 3-1-1 rule.  Thanks.

Comment: I typed human body and I got "Item not found" ;)

Comment: +1 for a pretty nifty tool. I checked it with random queries like `test tube` to see if items that can't be found in the database might be considered as allowed/forbidden but I did not manage to find any false negatives/positives.

Comment: @Phoog you should participate in the answerathon. See [meta].

Comment: Which is really interesting to me because wet wipes actually contain alcohol of some sort (at least ours do)

Comment: Search Results For: mother's ashes and urn

*Some airlines do not allow cremated remains as checked baggage, so please check with your airline to learn more about possible restrictions.*

Answer (score 8):

Thankfully **wet wipes are not yet subject to the 3-1-1 rule**. The [rule](http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/3-1-1-liquids-rule) applies to:

> Liquids, gels, aerosols, creams and pastes

Wet wipes don't fit in any of these categories.

I always travel with wet wipes in my carry-on and I have always been allowed on the plane with them.

Nevertheless, what happened twice in the last week (May 2016), as I was flying domestically within Schengen, was that my packet of wet wipes was mistaken for a water bottle by the officer behind the X-ray scanner. My bag was therefore hand checked by another officer who let me go without problems and with the wipes. This is to say that recently security checks might have been tightened and, if travelling with wet wipes in your carry-on, your luggage could be subject to a manual check by airport security. This happened at Luxembourg airport and Rome Fiumicino.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that TSA rules are not in force at Luxembourg airport or Rome Fiumicino.

Comment: It is not the TSA that does the checks in Europe, but most or even all of the rules are the same or very close alike. Changes can happen at different times.

Answer (score 2):

I routinely travel with pre-moistened wipes of various kinds in my carry-on bags.  Not only does the TSA not consider them a liquid, but neither do U.K. security (e.g., at LHR), which is far stricter than the TSA.  While wipes *contain* liquid, they are *not* themselves liquid.  Put more simply, there's no visible liquid when examining a moistened wipe.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume so. Since baby wipes are allowed, [according to the TSA website](http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/prohibited-items), I do not see the difference between baby wipes and wet wipes.