# Can I bring refreshing towels with alcohol with me for Canada flight?

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, hand-luggage, alcohol

I will be travelling to Canada this summer. I use refreshing towels from time to time. They are very good for cleaning dirt and oil from my hands. I searched for this on internet, however I see only people asking for wet wipes that *don't* contain alcohol.

The one I use has ethyl alcohol in it. I am confused because of the ingredients. Here is the pic of the package:

[image]

This packages are for 1 time use only. They come with a package of 50:

[image]

Can I take these with me?

Comment: Do you know the percentage of alcohol in them? There is a limit for airtravel. If the towel is below the limit, you can most likely take them with you (in your hand baggage) by putting them in your "liquids" bag within the allowance.

Comment: Where are you flying from?

Comment: I imagine the main reason people ask for wet wipes without alcohol is personal preference— they don't like the smell, or the dryness it causes, or they believe it damages their skin— rather than regulation.

Comment: I will fly from Germany. I don't know the percentage of alcohol but wipes dry out pretty quickly like 2-3 minutes after usage.

Answer (score 6):

I travel with similar Alcohol based hand wipes all the time.  The more common ones, like Wet-Ones are too slimy feeling...bleck.

I've never had an issue.  The amount of liquid is under any maximum allowed and there is far more alcohol in the galley and in checked baggage than could ever be carried in wipes.

Answer (score 3):

1. As for liquid rules, https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/44048/4188 discusses this: wet wipes are not subject to those as per TSA
2. As for alcohol at customs: these always contain isopropyl alcohol because that's an excellent solvent (indeed, my father's chemical laboratory literally had isopropyl alcohol on tap) and as such it has nothing to do with drinking alcohol (even if there's ethyl alcohol in there, it can't be separated out).